# CalledFromWrongThreadException occurs accidentally

Tags: android

A brief explanation of what I'm doing: my `FragmentActivity` hosts 4 Fragments via a `ViewPager`, those are created in my class which extends `Fragment`.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;
    switch (mPage) {

    case 1:

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,
                container, false);
        initFrag1(view);
        break;

    // ....... and so on

    }

    return view;
}
```

In the `onCreateView()` method I initialize the data depending on the page (Fragment). Each Fragment has quite a complex Layout with a LOT OF `TextViews`. That `FragmentActivity` gets started when the user clicks a `ListItem` in the previous `Activity`, and there's a delay of about 0.5-1 sec until the `FragmentActivity` starts. My consideration was that the delay is caused by initializing and setting tons of `TextViews`, so I tried to do all that stuff in an `AsyncTask`:

```
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    for (int i = 0; i < FirstTextViewArray.length; i++) {
        tmp = (TextView) v.findViewById(FirstTextViewArray[i]);
        tmp.setText("test " + String.valueOf(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SecondTextViewArray.length; i++) {
        tmp = (TextView) v.findViewById(SecondTextViewArray[i]);
        tmp.setText(df.format((SomeClass
                .getSomeFloatArray(Constants.tmpObject.getSomeInt())[i]));


    }
    return null;

}
```

So basically I'm just passing `TextViews` as `Arrays` and the inflated `View` to the `AsyncTask` in its constructor, then initialize and set them inside a loop.

It works BUT sometimes (like 1 out of 10) when I swipe between `Fragments` the app crashes with an Exception:

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

I know what that `Exception` means, but the question is: **why does it occur accidentally?**

2nd question: I guess init and set `Views` in the background is not the way to go. How can I then avoid delay at `Activity's` start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate method to safely update the UI on the UI thread. Here's a rough outline:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Object, Void>() {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        String label = (String) values[0];
        int viewId = (Integer) values[1];
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(viewId);
        tv.setText(label);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for (int i = 0; i < FirstTextViewArray.length; i++) {
            publishProgress("test " + String.valueOf(i), FirstTextViewArray[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SecondTextViewArray.length; i++) {
            publishProgress(
                    df.format((SomeClass.getSomeFloatArray(Constants.tmpObject.getSomeInt())[i])),
                    SecondTextViewArray[i]);


        }
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Another tip; For better performance don't fetch the views from the hierarchy _every_ time you need them. Keep references.

Comment: oh well, I used onProgressUpdate() for a ProgressBar in a player app, it's a shame I haven't considered doing the same to TextViews >< Thanks. I only need those Views once, my app display some stats from some game. After the Activity is set up, the user can only view the data displayed, and the TextViews will not change until the Activity gets closed and started again

Comment: The name of the method throws you off, but you can publish anything as progress, which turns out to be really powerful.

Comment: btw, do you have an idea why the exception I mentioned only occurs accidentally? Most of the time, setting those TextViews in doInBackground() works fine..

Comment: Not exactly sure under why the OS doesn't _always_ enforce the rule. Suppose it might only occur when you're trying to touch a View during a redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Only the main thread can work with the views, that's why you get this error.
You should use this thread :

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          //stuff that updates your views
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

          for (int i = 0; i < FirstTextViewArray.length; i++) {
              tmp = (TextView) v.findViewById(FirstTextViewArray[i]);
              tmp.setText("test " + String.valueOf(i));
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < SecondTextViewArray.length; i++) {
              tmp = (TextView) v.findViewById(SecondTextViewArray[i]);
              tmp.setText(df.format((SomeClass.getSomeFloatArray(Constants.tmpObject.getSomeInt())[i]));

          }
    }
});
```

So

Comment: the matter is that I used an AsyncTask to avoid delay on Activity's start. Using the method you mentioned there will be no difference if I use it or just perform my stuff after inflating the root View for the Fragment..?

Comment: It is cleaner to use "runOnUiThread" to update views.
If you need to perform a thread before rending your views, make an AsyncTask, then update the view with runOnUiThread.

I updated my code, but not tested it, but it should work like a charm.